# How can I display discount amount?

Tags: asp-classic

Please take a look at two connection strings, One to Access database and the other to SQL Server database.

The connection to Access database worked flawlessly until we recently changed hosting companies and moved to godaddy.com

They provided us with the connection string to SQL Server database.

Since then, we are unable to succecssfully connect to SQL Server. We kept getting 500 (internal error).

I tried contacting them and they kept telling us nobody else is having the same problem which I find very hard to believe.

Can you please see if you can find anything that I might be missing?

Many thanks to you all.

```
''# Access DB Connection String

<%
  Dim objConn, objRS
  ''# Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  ''# objConn.Open "DSN=ship"

 Set objConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objConn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
 "DATA SOURCE=" & server.mappath("admin\scart.mdb")

  Set objRS = objConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Username = '" & Request.Form("txtUsername") & "' AND password = '" & Request.Form("TxtPassword") & "' ")
  If Not objRS.EOF Then
    If objRS(1) = Request.Form("txtPassword") Then
      Session.Contents("access_level") = objRS(2)
      Session.Contents("ID") = objRS(3) ''#ID column
      Session("username") = objRS("USERNAME")
      Session("password") = objRS("password")
      Response.Redirect "setup.asp"
    Else
      Response.Write "Sorry, but the password that you entered is incorrect.&nbsp;<a href='setup.asp'>Try again</a>"
    End If
  Else
    Response.Write "Sorry, but the username that you entered does not exist.&nbsp;<a href='setup.asp'>Try again</a>"
  End If
  objRS.Close
  Set objRS = Nothing
  objConn.Close
  Set objConn = Nothing
%>


<%
''# SQL Server connection string
Dim objConn, objRS
Dim qry, connectstr
Dim db_name, db_username, db_userpassword
Dim db_server

db_server = "MyServer name"
db_name = "nyDBName"
db_username = "MyUsername"
db_userpassword = "MyPassword"

connectstr = "Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=" & db_server & ";DATABASE=" & db_name & ";UID=" & db_username & ";PWD=" & db_userpassword

Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open connectstr


  SQL = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Username = '" & Request.Form("txtUsername") & "' AND password = '" & Request.Form("TxtPassword") & "' "
  response.write sql
  response.end
  Set objRS = objConn.Execute(SQL)

  If Not objRS.EOF Then
    If objRS(1) = Request.Form("txtPassword") Then
      Session.Contents("access_level") = objRS(2)
      Session.Contents("ID") = objRS(3) ''# ID column
      Session("username") = objRS("USERNAME")
      Session("password") = objRS("password")
      Response.Redirect "setup.asp"
    Else
      Response.Write "Sorry, but the password that you entered is incorrect.&nbsp;<a href='setup.asp'>Try again</a>"
    End If
  Else
    Response.Write "Sorry, but the username that you entered does not exist.&nbsp;<a href='setup.asp'>Try again</a>"
  End If
  objRS.Close
  Set objRS = Nothing
  objConn.Close
  Set objConn = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Show us what line is the error occurring on.

Comment: Why would you move *to* GoDaddy?

Comment: Your path does not match the ones documented; http://help.godaddy.com/article/34 also you have a huge injection problem by not escaping submitted data/using a paramaterized  adodb.command

Comment: RedFilter, I can't tell the line. That's what I indicated in my post. I would have fixed it if I could tell what line the error is occuring. Besides, 500 internal error doesn't show error lines. thirtydot, I agree. It wasn't my decision. I actually tried to discourage it. I have not had warmed up to their service which I personally think sucks.  Alex, you showed a link that points to Access database connection. As stated, we are moving from Access to SQL Server. Actually, we wanted to stick with Access but they told us that in order to go to Access, we must move to their "legacy" server.

Comment: Yes but there is incorrect access related stuff in your example that will probably fail .. why is it there if its a prob with sql server? - enable detailed errors http://help.godaddy.com/article/3430

Comment: Can you kindly point out what incorrect access related stuff you notice? I went to the link you sent and it is talking about web.config but the app is classic asp not .net.

Comment: this is the link they pointed me. See the one that says, "Connecting to sql server using ADO/ASP  http://help.godaddy.com/search?q=asp+connecting+to+sql+server+database+&x=32&y=9

Comment: Ok, finally got it. The link I posted has paging enabled. I was able to page through it until I found the one that says, "Locate SQL Server connection strings. As you can see, this is different from what they gave me. connectstr = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DBname; User ID=UserName; Password='myPassword';" All is working now. Even though they said this is for .NET, it worked for classic asp.

Comment: @Chidi Okeh: Some advice, don't contactenate strings received from the client (and therefore potentially hostile) into SQL code that you execute.  Do some research on SQL Injection Attacks and use ADO parameterised queries instead.

Comment: Godaddy was a big mistake. They shoot elephants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it's not very clear whether you want to connect to the access/mdb or the sqlserver.

But anyway, one of the two articles below will cover you.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/259

http://support.godaddy.com/help/256/connecting-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-using-aspado

However, since in the code snippet you have shared with us, the userinput (Request.Form("txtUsername") is directly placed into the SQL statement **without any sanitization**, it's a matter of days that your database may be subjected to a big time SQL-Injection.

From this perspective, I can tell that you are lucky that you were not able to connect.

First and foremost, sanitize your userinput. Sanitization is a big sujbject. 
But try these as an immediate solution.

```
dim txtUsername,txtPassword
txtUsername = Request.Form("txtUsername") 
txtPassword = Request.Form("txtPassword")

'sanitize
txtPassword = replace(txtPassword,"'","''",1,-1,1)
txtUsername = replace(txtUsername,"'","''",1,-1,1) 

Set objRS = objConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Username = '" & txtUsername & "' AND password = '" & TxtPassword & "' ")
```

After fixing the code as above, then and only then, you should worry about fixing the original connection issue. So, pead about SQL Injection, and while you are at it, also read XSS ( Cross-Site-Scripting )

And make sure, every coder in your company read it and understand what these two things are. You will be glad you did. Or you guys will be in a miserable state sooner or later.

Good luck...